# Kafka consumer not receiving messages from some partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a consumer-group "mygroup1", with 2 consumers and subscribing to a topic "myapp.mymodule.mytopic". Topic has 12 partitions.

If I describe the consumer group, 'CURRENT-OFFSET' and 'LAG' for some of the partitions are shown as "-".

Any message that goes to these partitions are not received by any of the consumers if the message is published when the consumer is not active - even after the consumers comes up partitions are assigned. What could be the reason?

```
GROUP     TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                           HOST             CLIENT-ID
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   7          2               2               0               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   6          -               1               -               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   10         -               1               -               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   9          2               2               0               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   11         -               1               -               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   8          -               2               -               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   3          5               5               0               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   1          -               0               -               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   4          2               2               0               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   0          1               2               1               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   5          -               3               -               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   2          -               1               -               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
```

Also, it I shutdown both consumers in group and describe the group, it shows only the non-dash partitions

```
GROUP     TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                           HOST             CLIENT-ID
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   7          2               2               0               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   9          2               2               0               myconsumer-tsdmj-3542c522-e9a6-40ef-894f-635e5ec06393 /192.168.117.127 myconsumer-tsdmj
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   3          5               5               0               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   4          2               2               0               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
mygroup1  myapp.mymodule.mytopic   0          1               2               1               myconsumer-hr25g-a9b52d4f-3081-4035-80c2-48f2c0ed9849 /192.168.117.124 myconsumer-hr25g
```

Consumer properties are:

```
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, consumerId);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup1");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "120000");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "45000");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1");
```

Also, for legacy reasons, some other apps/compoenents also uses same group but subscribing to different topics. So there are more consumer in the group than what is shown below, but they subscribe to different topics.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This issue was resolved

This specific topic has sparse messages and retention value is also low. Looks like, when the purge happens, if there are no more messages left or may be because no commit for long time, the meta-data and 'CURRENT-OFFSET' is also seems to be lost for the group

Also, default value of "auto.offset.reset" is "latest". This caused that only the new messages published after the consumer started will be delivered as this is considered as a new consumer as earlier meta-data and 'CURRENT-OFFSET' is not there